# How to hook up to the onClick event of a QML item from C++ side

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qquickitem

**Scenario:**
I have a *Qt app* which runs on *Qt 5.9.4* commercial edition. Its a `QtQuick` and `QML` based application which is running on *iOS* and *Android*.

I have a `QML` item on the UI like this:

```
SomeItem {
    text: qsTr("Some Item")
    objectName: "someitem"
    visible: false
    onClicked: {
        console.log("Some item was clicked")
    }
}
```

I have a C++ function which can easily control the properties of `SomeItem`.

```
void MyCppClass::Func() {

    QQuickItem *someItem = qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("someitem");
    someItem->setVisible(true); // this works

    // How to listen to someItem's onClick event here
}
```

**Question:**
I want to listen to the onClick event of `someItem` in a C++ method or a lambda without changing anything in the QML. Basically hook up to the onClick signal signal of `someItem` from C++ side itself. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to use to interact can be dangerous in the general case because the life cycle of the items depends on QML, so make sure it does not happen. Going to your request and I assume that MyCppClass inherits from QObject or a child class you must create a slot and use the old connection syntax:

***.h**

```
class MyCppClass: public QObject
{
...
private slots:
    void on_clicked();
...
};
```

***.cpp**

```
void MyCppClass::Func() {

    QQuickItem *someItem = qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("someitem");
    if(!someItem)
        return;
    someItem->setVisible(true); // this works
    connect(someItem, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_clicked()));

}

void MyCppClass::on_clicked(){
    qDebug()<<"on clicked";
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is special case which I need do. Confirming that its well within the point of existence of the QML item this logic depends on.